# WordPress combined with a basic MYSQL table

Tags: custom-post-types

thanks in advance for any feedback to help me find a solution.

== Context ==

I have my website made in wordpress, in which I have a list of cars that must come from another table in MYSQL (because that list is loaded from a different system in wordpress)

Currently what I do is insert a shortcode on a page that queries that table and displays the list of cars.

Then when clicking on car specifically the user is directed to another page and in the URL I send a variable that is car_code

On the next page I have another shortcode that takes the variable $_GET['car_code']

and consult in this table the details of the car to expand the information to the user

== Questions ==
This works fine, but I think there must be a better way to do it and I'd like some help if possible:

I am currently having difficulties because:

1. To do SEO, each cart is not indexed by Google independently because it does not have independent URLs. This could be solved with something from the modrewrite I suppose.
2. I don't have each cart individually in my wordpress to make changes to each cart if I want (This seems to be little necessary)

== Solution Approaches ==

I am thinking of possible solutions, among them the following

1. Every time a cart is published in the cart table, create a custom post type in my wordpress.
2. Having the possibility of creating custom post ype on the fly, that is, tricking wordpress into believing that a custom posttype exists only for programming but that it is false.

What other ideas can you give me, a different or better way to handle this situation?